# How to code once before and once after all junit5 tests have executed in a module?

Tags: java, junit5

I have a multi module project spring boot project, where each module produces a jar. Each module has a `src/main/test` with junit 5 tests. Is there a way to run code before and after all the tests in `src/main/test` in a specific module execute?  For example if I have 2 modules A, and B I want.

- run code before all tests in module A execute
- run code all tests module A execute
- run code before all tests in module B execute
- run code after all tests in module B execute

Comment: If all test are in a class then @BeforeClass annotation does the Job. Do I think wrong?

Comment: @sfarbac JUnit5 has renamed the annotation `@BeforeClass` to `@BeforeAll`

Comment: I am not  talking  about order of  test methods. I am talking about before all tests in a src/main/test run and after all of them have finished running. for example tearning down a database after all test  are run in a module.

Comment: I suggest to take a look on the junit jupiter listener https://stackoverflow.com/a/66110856/296328

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of inheritance and the annotation [`@BeforeAll`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeAll.html), optionally with a flag to execute only once for all inheriting test classes.

```
public class ModuleBaseClass {

  private static boolean started = false;

  @BeforeAll
  public static void beforeAllMethod() {
      if (!started) {
          System.out.println("@BeforeAll static method invoked once.");
          started = true;
      }
      System.out.println("@BeforeAll static method invoked for every class.");
  }
}

public class ModuleFeature1Class extends ModuleBaseClass {

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
      System.out.println("ModuleFeature1Class: in testMethod().");
  }
}

public class ModuleFeature2Class extends ModuleBaseClass {

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
      System.out.println("ModuleFeature2Class: in testMethod().");
  }
}
```

This will print:

```
@BeforeAll static method invoked once.
@BeforeAll static method invoked for every class.
ModuleFeature1Class: in testMethod().
@BeforeAll static method invoked for every class.
ModuleFeature2Class: in testMethod().
```

In the same manner you can use the annotation [@AfterAll](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.jupiter.api/org/junit/jupiter/api/AfterAll.html) to execute after your tests.

Comment: @BeforeAll works on test methods in a class  it does not work across a collection of  classes containing test methods.

Comment: ams, thats the point of the boolean started

Answer (score 1):

You can define the order for methods in a test class, but not for order of test classes.

There is an open request for this feature, but there's no word yet if JUnit will implement it: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1948