# Run code in junit 5 after all tests in all test classes terminated

Tags: java, maven, junit5

For test evidence I would like to archive all tests artifacts (like eg Server calls and responses) that I wrote into a specific directory. I got the method to zip the directory, but I din't find a suitable place to execute it.

The test life cycle callbacks don't seem to be the right place since @AfterAll is called after each test class, but the archive should be generated after all tests in all test classes terminated.

After reading posts like [How to code once before and once after all junit5 tests have executed in a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61005947/how-to-code-once-before-and-once-after-all-junit5-tests-have-executed-in-a-modul) there seems to be little hope to execute the call from within junit.

I found an extension TestLauncher, but after reading the scarce documentation this rather seems to be used to start the tests from the outside. Especially the SummaryGeneratingListener sounds useful for extending after reading https://www.codota.com/web/assistant/code/rs/5c7c89fd2f7dae0001637b13#L33 but if I put this code in the tree under mavens src/test I don't see how only this launcher will be called and not all the single tests as well...

Since the code will eventually run in a maven build where the archiving really matters I thought maybe there is a possibility to run it after target test. But I understood that maven stops if there at least a certain amount of errors in the test target and then the following code will not be executed. But it's the error situation where the evidence will be most useful.

Did anybody try something similar?

Thanks for sharing thoughts, ideas and experience

Comment: It would be interesting to know why you like to archive all artifacts? Do you use a ci solution like Jenkins? What kind of artifacts do you produce during a test?

Comment: The main reason to save the artifacts is test evidence for end to end test that I execute using junit. More and more auditors demand prove that a program was tested and how. But also for business and as documentation for dev and qa. I try to write for each test a human readable test report that "self-documents" the test. In addition I write the requests and responses in separate files, that are linked in the test report. This provides a high level description where you can drill down to each action and replay. This improves transparency, provides actual doc and easy analysis...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general there are several solutions for the problem.

- You could define the beforeAll/afterAll on a parent class from which all of your tests inherit. Another option would be to try to define the beforeAll/afterAll on an interface (I'm not 100% sure if this works; I would say it should). In beforeAll you could initialize your setup and in the afterEachCallBack your can collect all the data you need for a single test. So this is called after each test.
- You could implement an extension which uses the [callbacks of JUnit](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-execution-order-overview) which are [BeforeAllCallback](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-lifecycle-callbacks) and [AfterAllCallBack](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-lifecycle-callbacks) which could handle that. Based on what you exactly need you may need to implement beforeEachCallBack/afterEachCallBack as well.
- Another option would be to use the [Test Execution listener](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api-listeners-custom)
  where you can use `testPlanExecutionStarted` and `testPlanExecutionFinished` which you should implemented to record and get all you need.

I've made an [example project](https://github.com/khmarbaise/junit-jupiter-listener) which shows the usage of the JUnit Jupiter listener.

Comment: Hei Karl, thank you so much for that super cool example project! So easy I get ashamed, but that's the way to go. I was thinking and reading a long time the AfterAllCallBack, but for a couple of reasons that seemed to me too isolated. And most of all, there must be toggle to switch the report on and off: It is not needed per default for the daily build, as long as it's green, but might be useful when it turns red. And it is most wanted before the release.

Comment: Usually you can record/archive those things with your ci and keep the records only for a few days (depeding on the size)...

Comment: If you build is red that should already produced the appropriate report. So turning off/on does not make sense from my point of view.

Comment: I know those reports, I had to stand them for years. To me they look rather like a dump with thousands of lines with shredded information. If I manage to create a more readable report, I will ask you to challenge it if you want. But free from personal taste I would like to thank you for your input which is really great, lean and very good matching..

Comment: "You could define the beforeAll/afterAll on a parent class from which all of your tests inherit." No, this doesn't solve it.

Comment: A single BeforeAll/AfterAll does not work across a collection of classes as it will execute once per class.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use shutdownhook in extension.
For example:

```
public class GameMockExtension extends MockitoExtension {
  static Level level;
  static{
    level.init();
    Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
        level.close();
    });
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(t);
  }
}
```